# How to show $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$ without using $(X^*,wk^*)^*\subseteq X^{**}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-topology

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $x\in X$. Then $x$ defines a linear functional $\hat{x}$ on $X^*$ via $\hat{x}(f)=f(x)$ $(f\in X^*)$.

From this definition we can easily get $\hat{x}$ is weak* continuous on $X^*$. Therefore, we have $\hat{x}\in (X^*,wk^*)^*$.

Now let $X$ be a normed space. My question is from $\hat{x}\in (X^*,wk^*)^*$ how can we get $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$ without using $(X^*,wk^*)^*\subseteq X^{**}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to show that $\hat x$ is bounded, it is simply 
$$
|\hat x(f)|=|f(x)|\leq\|f\|\,\|x\|
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we use the fact $\hat{x}\in (X^*,wk^*)^*$ to get $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you expect: it is well-known that  $(X^*,wk^*)^*=X$.

Comment: I am sorry if I make you confused. I saw a conclusion on a paper and it is:  $\hat{x}\in (X^*, wk^*)^*$, and hence $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$. I just don't know how he gets it. Is it because some property about weak star topology? Thank you!

Comment: As I said, if $\hat x\in (X^*,wk^*)^*$, then $\hat x\in X$ (so, in particular, it is in $X^{**}$. It is not entirely obvious, but it is not a very complicated proof either. I've seen the result in Conway's Functional Analysis book, but it should also be elsewhere.

Comment: How to get $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$ from $\hat{x}\in X$?

Comment: That's what the hat usually means. For any $x\in X$, $\hat x(f)=f(x)$ gives $\hat x\in X^{**}$. It's the canonical inclusion $X\subset X^{**}$ that one considers every time duality is discussed.